# Arithmetic Derivative on sum of two perfect squares

Tags: number-theory, sums-of-squares

Let $n,m \in \mathbb N$ and $n$ even, $m$ odd. If we take there squares and add them $n^2+m^2$, are there examples when we take the arithmetic derivative of the sum:

$(n^2+m^2)' \equiv 0 \mod 4$ ?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A003415/b003415.txt

Comment: @WillJagy thank you. I did try to check by looking at examples but I could not find any where they divide 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$  625 = 5^4 = 20^2 + 15^2  $$

Comment: I would be interested if there are any which do not add to a square?